# Creating a specific symbol without the text tag in SVG

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to figure out how to properly edit SVG files. I have the following code:

```html
<svg width="80" height="50" viewBox="0 0 80 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="80" height="50" rx="4" fill="#497284" fill-opacity="0.09"/>
<path d="M70 11.8092V11.5C70 8.42972 68.2774 6 64.6107 6C60.8949 6 59 8.38554 59 11.5663C59 14.6145 61.1409 17 64.66 17C66.8993 17 68.9172 15.9618 70 14.1727L68.1298 13.2229C67.2931 14.4598 66.3826 15.2329 64.6846 15.2329C62.5682 15.2329 61.2394 13.5763 61.2148 11.8092H70ZM61.3378 10.3072C61.6085 8.82731 62.8881 7.72289 64.6107 7.72289C66.3826 7.72289 67.5145 8.76104 67.7852 10.3072H61.3378Z" fill="#586D8C"/>
</svg>
```

it creates a box with a letter 'e' in the corner. I want to change the letter to be some sign (in my case - the logical operator 'NOT' sign). I found out that I could use the `text` tag as follows:

```html
<svg width="80" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect fill="none" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect x="0.114941" y="0.229882" id="svg_1" fill-opacity="0.09" fill="#497284" rx="4" height="50" width="80"/>
  <path id="svg_2" fill="#586D8C" d="m57.5,34c4.1421,0 7.5,-3.3579 7.5,-7.5c0,-4.1421 -3.3579,-7.5 -7.5,-7.5c-3.803,0 -6.9451,2.8306 -7.434,6.5l-37.066,0l0,3l37.2697,0c0.8752,3.1711 3.7808,5.5 7.2303,5.5z" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
  <text transform="matrix(1.6882815594622569,0,0,1.3037036829424493,-58.03884193994182,9.82972205136589) " xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_7" y="10.069448" x="66.18055" stroke-width="0" fill="#586D8C">¬</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

But I prefer not to. I'm trying to figure a way to create that symbol with the `path` tag. The wanted final result should be:

[image]

What is the proper way to achieve it?

Comment: Use Inkscape or some other tool to convert the letter to a path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create this path by following the text shape. In the next example I'm creating a path filled with black. Please observe that the commands of the path are all relative and the first command `M0,0` starts the path in the origin (0,0). You can either translate the path where you need it (`transform="translate(55.5,10.5)"`) or you can change the first command from `M0,0` to what you need without changing the rest of the path. In this case the first command may be: `M55.5,10.5`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 50" >
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect x="0.114941" y="0.229882" id="svg_1" fill-opacity="0.09" fill="#497284" rx="4" height="50" width="80"/>
  <!--<text transform="matrix(1.6882815594622569,0,0,1.3037036829424493,-58.03884193994182,9.82972205136589) " xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_7" y="10.069448" x="66.18055" stroke-width="0" fill="#586D8C">¬</text>-->
   <path d="M0,0h20.5v9h-3v-6.5h-17.5z" transform="translate(55.5,10.5)" />
 </g>
</svg>
```